Visual Studio C++ Influence Up-To-Date Check
I have a project that copies certain files to its output folder on build. The problem is these files can change independent of the actual project, at which point Visual Studio claims that everything is up-to-date and does not run my copy tasks.
Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to run a target/copy job if certain input files changed?
The original solution was the following (documentation):
  <Target Name="CopyDependencies" BeforeTargets="Build" 
      Inputs="AbsolutePath\To\SomeFile.txt" 
      Outputs="$(OutDir)\SomeFile.txt">
    <Copy SourceFiles="AbsolutePath\To\SomeFile.txt" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)" />
  </Target>

but that results in
1>------ Up-To-Date check: Project: MyProject.vcxproj, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>All outputs are up-to-date.

even if I write to SomeFile.txt after the last build.
I also tried to manually create a CC.write.1.tlog file (before spending the time writing the code to generate it automatically) with:
^ABSOLUTE\PATH\TO\SOMEFILE.TXT
ABSOLUTE\PATH\TO\OUTDIR\SOMEFILE.TXT

to see if that would make VS consider the file as input in its up-to-date algorithm, but that also fails.

If you have a copy of the project which has already been built and nothing has changed since except the AbsolutePath\To\SomeFile.txt, is the desired behavior that the new SomeFile.txt will be copied and all other steps in the build will be skipped as "up to date", i.e. there will be no compile step?

@JonathanDodds Nice to have, but I don't mind the extra unnecessary work happening once in a while. Certainly preferable to broken compilations.

How do you have broken compilations?

@jonathan By outdated files being part of the output despite me telling the build system that some of its inputs changed.

Oh - so you don't literally mean a compiler error. And you don't mean that the build fails with an error. You mean that the build completes successfully but is "bad" because your external file is not updated in the output directory. Is that correct? It makes a difference in understanding the issue. When a source file is out of date and the Compile step is performed, is the external file copied?

@Jonathan There's no need for scare quotes, the result is simply wrong - I tell msbuild about build dependencies (which msbuild gets perfectly right). Visual Studio which simply has an optimization which results in incorrect behavior. And yes the Copy task works perfectly fine if it's run.

I'm trying to understand what is happening. When you write "broken compilations", the meaning for me is there are one or more compiler errors.  A result that is considered wrong by you (i.e. "bad") is a different case from a result that is an error message (e.g. a compiler error). The latter is a broken compilation. The former is not. I suspect that "Visual Studio optimizing and creating incorrect behavior" is not what is happening. I suspect that the CopyDependencies target is only run when both of the following are true: SomeFile.txt is out of date and the compilation step needs to run.

I copied your target into my .vcxproj file and can reproduce the same issue at my side.  I found a workaround to avoid skipping target "CopyDependencies" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input file even if you write to SomeFile.txt after the last build.
Please set the property DisableFastUpToDateCheck as true in the Globals property group of your project file to override the visual studio behavior.
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <DisableFastUpToDateCheck>true</DisableFastUpToDateCheck>
</PropertyGroup>

As the doc noted,

A boolean value that applies to Visual Studio only. The Visual Studio build manager uses a process called FastUpToDateCheck to determine whether a project must be rebuilt to be up to date. This process is faster than using MSBuild to determine this. Setting the DisableFastUpToDateCheck property to true lets you bypass the Visual Studio build manager and force it to use MSBuild to determine whether the project is up to date.

Besides, you can run msbuild command to watch the process of build like this and see MSBuild determine whether the project is up to date.


UPDATE

I guess that would be a workaround, but comes with performance implications.

Yes, disabling the VS fast up-to-date check will make your builds much slower. Instead, you can use UpToDateCheckInput and UpToDateCheckOutput to describe an input/output file that MSBuild would not otherwise know about.
<ItemGroup>
  <UpToDateCheckInput Include="bsolutePath\To\SomeFile.txt"" />
  <UpToDateCheckOutput Include="$(OutDir)\SomeFile.txt"" />
</ItemGroup>

In your case you can also use UpToDateCheckBuilt as there is both an input and an output. If certain input files changed, it is rebuilt.
<ItemGroup>
    <UpToDateCheckBuilt Include="$(OutDir)\SomeFile.txt"" Original="AbsolutePath\To\SomeFile.txt" />
</ItemGroup>

Docs referred:
up-to-date-check

I guess that would be a workaround, but comes with performance implications that I'm not too happy with for a rare edge case.

Hi @Voo, yes, it will make your builds much slower. I have found another workaround. Updated the answer.
